# Reactive Extensions: The trouble with Where()

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I love Rx, but I have a problem I keep running into.

Let's say we have a single upstream `IObservable<Foo>`, and `N` downsteam sequences attached to it, where each is only interested in those Foos that satisfy some simple predicate (say `foo.bar == someKey`).

Of course this is a simple job for the `Where()` operator:

```
IObservable<Foo> foos = ...;
foos.Where(foo => foo.bar == "abc").Subscribe(f => A(f));
foos.Where(foo => foo.bar == "xyz").Subscribe(f => B(f));
foos.Where(foo => foo.bar == "bla").Subscribe(f => C(f));
...
[many more subscriptions for different bar values]
```

What will essentially happen here is that for each `Foo` produced upstream, the `Where()` predicate will be evaluated for that `Foo` `N` times. It acts like a linear search to find all subscribers that want this `Foo`. That's all well and good, and exactly what we (should) expect from using `Where()` here.

The problem I have is that in my case, `N` may be very large, but the subset of subscribers that want any particular `Foo` is very small. Typically, there will be only one for each `Foo`. This means I'm essentially doing a slow linear search when I could be doing a very efficient lookup to find the few downstream sequences that this `Foo` needs to be propagated too. My apps run in a very performance critical environment and I cannot afford this inefficiency.

I've racked my brain trying to find some elegant way of doing this more efficiently, but I can only come up with solutions that involve storing a lot of state (mapping subscribers, etc) and having to manage concurrency very carefully, which defeats a lot of the purpose of using Rx in the first place. I would prefer some way of dealing with this in terms of existing operators. Has anyone dealt with this issue before, or know of a good solution? I'm happy to provide more details.

**EDIT**

I guess my example was a bit too simplistic. I'm not dealing with a case where I'm matching against numeric values within some known bound. N was just for illustration purposes. Updated example above.

Comment: will you have foos for all possible values of bar 0..N, or just for some?

Comment: the best will probably be to keep your foos in sorted order. Take a look at `List.BinarySearch`, and then just iterate calling `Subscribe` until `foo.Bar >= N`

Comment: Sorry, my example was too simplistic, see edit and new example code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got a great solution from Dave Sexton over at the Rx discussion board on Codeplex:

https://rx.codeplex.com/discussions/439717

> How about using **GroupBy** or **GroupByUntil** with **Publish**?
>
> For example: (*Untested*)
>
> ```
> IConnectableObservable<IGroupedObservable<string, Foo>> foosByBar = 
>     (from foo in foos
>      group foo by foo.bar)
>     .Publish();
>
> foosByBar.Where(g => g.Key == "abc").Take(1).SelectMany(g => g).Subscribe(A);
> foosByBar.Where(g => g.Key == "xyz").Take(1).SelectMany(g => g).Subscribe(B);
> foosByBar.Where(g => g.Key == "bla").Take(1).SelectMany(g => g).Subscribe(C);
>
> foosByBar.Connect();
> ```
>
> **GroupBy** uses a dictionary lookup for every key to find the appropriate observable in which the value is pushed.
>
> **Publish** broadcasts the group-by so that the dictionary lookup operation is shared by all observers.
>
> **Where** / **Take** executes the predicate only once to locate the appropriate group, then it receives a broadcast of every value in that
>   group along with any other observers interested in the same key.
>
> Note that **GroupBy** doesn't replay **IGroupedObservable** so you
>   must set up all of your subscriptions before connecting. If you'd
>   rather use **RefCount** than **Connect**, then perhaps you should
>   consider applying the **Replay** operator to the result of
>   **GroupBy**.

Comment: Why don't you publish the solution they found there into this answer?

Comment: I figured it's better to get the info from the source, but I did it anyway in case CodePlex explodes one day.

Answer (score 0):

Something is storing the state, right now it's just the observable storing all the subscribers you added through the Wheres.  It's not clear if you realize this, but foos must notify each of its observers on every message.  All `Where` does is make it so most of the observers simply check against the predicate and return, but each predicate is checked for every message.

Building a map of handlers that is wrapped up as an observer would not be too difficult and should net you the performance gains you want.  Simply register as many handlers as you need and then subscribe the map to the source observable.  If a `Dictionary` doesn't provide the matching semantics you need, you will have to come up with some other scheme to reduce the lookups, but the overall idea would be the same.  Note that you can register the same handler multiple times if it has multiple inputs it should handle and you can register multiple handlers for the same input.

```
class ObserverMap<T> : IObserver<T>
{
    ObserverMap(Action<Exception> onError, Action onCompleted)
    {
        _onError = onError;
        _onCompleted = onCompleted;
        _handlers = new Dictionary<T, List<Action<T>>>();
    }
    ObserverMap(Action<Exception> onError, Action onCompleted, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer) 
    {
        _onError = onError;
        _onCompleted = onCompleted;
        _handlers = new Dictionary<T, List<Action<T>>>(comparer);
    }

    int _stopped;
    Dictionary<T, List<Action<T>>> _handlers;
    Action<Exception> _onError;
    Action _onCompleted;

    public void OnCompleted()
    {
        if (System.Threading.Interlocked.Exchange(ref _stopped, 1) == 0)
        {
            if (_onCompleted != null) _onCompleted();
        }
    }

    public void OnError(Exception error)
    {
        if (System.Threading.Interlocked.Exchange(ref _stopped, 1) == 0)
        {
            if (_onCompleted != null) _onCompleted();
        }
    }

    public void OnNext(T value)
    {
        if (_stopped != 0) return;

        List<Action<T>> match;
        if (_handlers.TryGetValue(value, out match))
        {
            foreach (var handler in match)
            {
                handler(value);
            }
        }
    }

    public IDisposable RegisterHandler(T key, Action<T> handler)
    {
        if (handler == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("handler");

        List<Action<T>> match;
        if (!_handlers.TryGetValue(key, out match))
        {
            match = new List<Action<T>>();
            _handlers.Add(key, match);
        }
        match.Add(handler);

        return System.Reactive.Disposables.Disposable.Create(() => match.Remove(handler));
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest, instead of writing a method with a signature `IDisposable RegisterHandler(T key, Action<T> handler)` for adding subscribers, write a indexer-property/method with the signature more like `IObservable<T> this[T key] { get { return Observable.Create(...); } }`.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that state is being stored and of the notifications for each oberver (this is what I meant when I described the linear search). Rx tucks this away neatly though, and I'd rather not have to write this kind of code myself. I do have a solution similar to what you describe, but I'm hoping there's a cleaner "built-in" way.